# How to make commons methods for a few classes(Java, Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, methods

I have two methods in my controllers that I should insert in each controller. Code of these methods are changed depending on the controller.

For example, I have:

```
private T1 variantDTO(Variant variant, T2 entity) {
        if (variant == null) variant = Variant.DEFAULT;
        switch (variant) {
            case ID:
                return T3.toIdDTO(entity);
            default:
                return T3.toDTO(entity);
        }
    }

    private List<? extends T1> variantDTOList(Variant variant, List<T2> entityList) {
        if (variant == null) variant = Variant.DEFAULT;
        switch (variant) {
            case ID:
                return T3.toIdDTOList(entityList);
            default:
                return T3.toDTOList(entityList);
        }
    }
```

T1, T2, T3 should be changed in each controller.

T3 is autowired field.

For example:

```
@Autowired
EntityMapper entityMapper;
```

And then:

```
//...
case ID:
   return entityMapper.toIdDTOList(entityList);
//...
```

I can't understand how to do this.

Can you help me? What should I do? When I want to change these methods I should do it in a few controllers. It's very hard.

**UPDATE:**

I try to do a common parametric class with these methods that I want to inheritance in my controllers. But I get errors in methods(toIdDTO, toDTO, ...)

```
public class VariantController<Abstract, Entity, Mapper> {

    @Autowired
    Mapper mapper;

    private Abstract variantDTO(Variant variant, Entity entity) {
        if (variant == null) variant = Variant.DEFAULT;
        switch (variant) {
            case ID:
                return mapper.toIdDTO(entity);
            default:
                return mapper.toDTO(entity);
        }
    }

    private List<? extends Abstract> variantDTOList(Variant variant, List<Entity> entityList) {
        if (variant == null) variant = Variant.DEFAULT;
        switch (variant) {
            case ID:
                return mapper.toIdDTOList(entityList);
            default:
                return mapper.toDTOList(entityList);
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

> Cann't resolve method toIdDTO(entity)

**UPDATE2**:

I have a different mapper in each controller.

**UPDATE3** - Full Example:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/groupsparameters")
public class GroupParametersController {

    @Autowired
    private GroupParameterService groupParameterService;

    @Autowired
    private GroupParameterMapper groupParameterMapper;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<? extends GroupParameterAbstract> get(@PathVariable Long id,
                                                                              @RequestParam(value = "variant", required = false) Variant variant) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        GroupParameter groupParameter = groupParameterService.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(variantDTO(variant, groupParameter), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<? extends GroupParameterAbstract>> findAll(@RequestParam(value = "variant", required = false) Variant variant,
                                                                          @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search) {

        List<GroupParameter> groupParameterList = groupParameterService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(variantDTOList(variant, groupParameterList), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private GroupParameterAbstract variantDTO(Variant variant, GroupParameter entity) {
        if (variant == null) variant = Variant.DEFAULT;
        switch (variant) {
            case ID:
                return groupParameterMapper.toIdDTO(entity);
            default:
                return groupParameterMapper.toDTO(entity);
        }
    }

    private List<? extends GroupParameterAbstract> variantDTOList(Variant variant, List<GroupParameter> entityList) {
        if (variant == null) variant = Variant.DEFAULT;
        switch (variant) {
            case ID:
                return groupParameterMapper.toIdDTOList(entityList);
            default:
                return groupParameterMapper.toDTOList(entityList);
        }
    }

}
```

Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { TypeReportService.class})
public interface GroupParameterMapper {

    //GroupParatemerDTO
    GroupParameterDTO toDTO(GroupParameter groupParameter);
    List<GroupParameterDTO> toDTOList(List<GroupParameter> groupParameterList);

    //GroupParameterIdDTO
    @Mapping(target = "typeReportId", source = "typeReport.id")
    GroupParameterIdDTO toIdDTO(GroupParameter groupParameter);
    List<GroupParameterIdDTO> toIdDTOList(List<GroupParameter> groupParameterList);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "typeReport", source ="typeReportId", qualifiedByName = { "findTypeReportById" })
    GroupParameter fromIdDTO(GroupParameterIdDTO groupParameterIdDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException;

    //GroupParameter
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "common", ignore = true)
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE)
    void fill(GroupParameter source, @MappingTarget GroupParameter target);

}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class GroupParameter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ID_GENERATOR)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean common;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_REPORT_ID", nullable = false)
    private TypeReport typeReport;

}
```

DTO:

```
@Data
public abstract class GroupParameterAbstract {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean common;

}

public class GroupParameterDTO extends GroupParameterAbstract {

}

@Data
public class GroupParameterIdDTO extends GroupParameterAbstract {

    private Long typeReportId;

}
```

Comment: How about just using inheritance?

Comment: One simple way would be to create a BaseController and extend that to your other controllers with common functionality. Or else create a Utility that would keep this piece of code and can be used where ever you want to.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I add what I try to do. Can you see it? I get an error.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma I add what I try to do. Can you see it? I get an error.

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin Could you please add a minimum working code to reproduce this?

Comment: @AshutoshSharma I've added a full code of Controller, Entity, DTOs, and Mapper in question.

Comment: Why not using creating the methods in a service and just inject it in each controller. As long as the methods are no endpoints you don't need them in the controller. It would be a better way to seperate the logic from the api.